# Docker-compose with secrets from Azure key-vault secret in multi-container linux web app

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

Is there a way to set ENV variable from azure key-vault secret for a multi-container linux web app?
I am able to set the ENV variables in the `app_config` from key-vault secret using the `@Microsoft.KeyVault` reference (base on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#source-app-settings-from-key-vault)).
[image]

This is good for the single container apps, but I have a multi-container app, and I would like to set some environment variables for specific services inside the multi-container app.
I did try using the `@Microsoft.KeyVault` reference inside the `docker-compose.yml` file, but that is not working - it is simply returning the string I am setting.

My question would be if we can do something like this that would return the actual value of the key-vault secret:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  my_service:
    image: <IMAGE_TAG_HERE>
    environment:
      - TEST_KEY=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=my-secret-vault;SecretName=my-secret-key)
  my_second_service:
    image: <IMAGE_TAG_HERE>
    environment:
      - SECOND_SERVICE_TEST_KEY=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=my-secret-vault;SecretName=my-second-service-secret-key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application settings provide environment variables for your application and therefore, in your case, for your docker-compose. You can't reference your KeyVault directly in your docker-compose because compose does not know how to interprete it. You have to do it in your application settings (as you did for a container) and then tell your docker-compose to look in the environment variable.

So, after setting up your application with the KeyVault reference, update your docker-compose like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  my_service:
    image: <IMAGE_TAG_HERE>
    environment:
      - TEST_KEY=${<APP_SETTING_NAME_FOR_TEST_KEY>}
  my_second_service:
    image: <IMAGE_TAG_HERE>
    environment:
      - SECOND_SERVICE_TEST_KEY=${<APP_SETTING_NAME_FOR_SECOND_SERVICE_TEST_KEY>}
```

This `${}` notation can also be used locally with a ".env" file.

Comment: as I saw, if I set an ENV variable in the app settings, that variable will be available in all the services within the multi-container app.
this is what I would like to avoid - only set environment variables for specific services within the multi-container app

Comment: hmm indeed. But I think the layer added by docker compose will filter what containers can see based on the "environment" property and won't send "everything". What do you think?

Comment: I will give that a try - it will be great if it will work like that. I will let you know about the results.

Comment: just checked, and even though I added only 3 variables from the app settings, when I access the main service via SSH I can still see all the environment variables from the app settings. 

I will probably set them in the app setting and have them in each service for now, and I will search for a better solution after this. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: By "the main service via SSH" do you mean one of your docker service or Kudu console?